# Script in R returning numeric(0) and I cannot solve

Tags: r, for-loop, integral

I have made a script to calculate the line integral in a matrix of cartesian coordinates points:

```
# Line Integral (Discrete)
# Input dataSet(as a matrix)
LineInt <- function(dataSet)
{
    Dist = 0;
    L = nrow(dataSet)
    for (idx in 1: L - 1)
     {
                    Dist = Dist +  (   ( (dataSet[idx + 1, 1] - dataSet[idx ,1])^2) + ((dataSet[idx + 1, 2] - dataSet[idx, 2])^2)  )^(1/2)
     }
    return(Dist)
}
```

The script just have to get the diference between next point and actual point, calculate the module of the distance and storage in a variable, then the variable is returned. But for some reason I am getting numeric(0) for all the inputs. I am a beginner and I still cannot find the solution in other topics.

Comment: I would recommend to use the R code style (<-, no ;, etc), also some example data would be useful to provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Use parentheses, like `1:(L-1)`

Answer (score 0):

Indexing of idx to Dist variable should be done, hope you may get the solution

```
 LineInt <- function(dataSet)
    {
        Dist = 0;
        L = nrow(dataSet)
        for (idx in 1: (L - 1))
         {
           Dist[idx] = Dist +  (   ( (dataSet[idx + 1, 1] - dataSet[idx ,1])^2) + ((dataSet[idx + 1, 2] - dataSet[idx, 2])^2)  )^(1/2)
         }
        return(Dist)
    }
```